# Android protobuf-lite toString not working

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, tostring, pretty-print

I'm trying to pretty print the content of a protobuf message in my android app for debuging puprose but when I call .toString() on a message this is what I get:

> request is # a.e.c.a$a@7baa4

How can I print the content of a message?

Answer (score 3):

protobuf-lite does not support `toString()`. It can't, because `TextFormat` relies on protobuf reflection and descriptors, which are exactly the features that are omitted in lite mode. You will need to build against regular (non-lite) protobufs for this to work.

Comment: I have tried doing so in android but I cannot manage to the the projerect to build. it I use the standar protobuf-java it complains "missing protoc: stdout: . stderr: Missing output directives. Could you show me a working example for android using the non-lite version ?

Comment: https://github.com/yurifariasg/android-google-speech-sample  ithink its protobut 2 , nano, android. its a much bigger build so u will probably need to look at 'multidex' revs to the project to get a good build

Comment: @Johny19 Sorry, I don't personally have experience using Protobuf on Android. A different approach you might want to try is to dump the encoded protobuf to a file, then use `protoc --decode` to read it. Then you don't need to change how you app is built.

Comment: This what I did in the end but its painfull as hell. But because I don't like to give up I have created a fresh project from start, clean gradle, still with protobuf-light and for a  DAMN reason .toString now works :/ (the only dif is that i'm using version 3.0.0 instead of 3.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using proguard rule.
GeneratedMessageLite class override toString method. And that method use `get` and `set` and `has` methods. So I add that method to proguard rule

```
# for toString debug
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite {
  *** get*();
  *** set*(***);
  *** has*();
}
```